# Pull in external config file

Tags: docker

I am needing to pull content from a directory with config files. I need to copy the contents out of the config files into files on the docker container. Do I have to mount that folder as a volume on the docker container then unmount at the end?

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

ARG DEPLOY_BRANCH

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libssl-dev \
        unzip \
        git \
        wget \
        ssh

RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg make g++ \
        && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
        && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN git clone https://github.com/jbboehr/php-psr.git
WORKDIR php-psr
RUN phpize \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make test \
    && make install


RUN git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git /cphalcon
WORKDIR /cphalcon/build
RUN ./install
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini \
    && touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/psr.ini \
    && echo "extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/phalcon.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini \
    && echo "extension=psr.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/psr.ini

RUN git clone https://project.git /opt/application
WORKDIR /opt/application/auto
RUN git checkout $DEPLOY_BRANCH


RUN touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys / && chmod 666 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN echo "pull from file" >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN npm install phantomjs

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN echo "
pull from file
" >> /etc/apache2/application.conf

RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just use the ADD command to add files from your local to the container:

```
ADD RELATIVE_PATH_TO_FOLDER_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD_CONTENT/* FOLDER_IN_CONTAINER/
```